# Xcode4 distribution certificate

Tags: xcode, xcode4, certificate, distribution

I've looking for in many places but I didn't find something useful for me. My problem is:

I have my distribution certificate in my keychan and appear in my windows organizer. But when I try to select it from my list of code signing doesn't appear. Just my provisional certificate.

I've deleted all certificates of my keychan, downloaded again and the distribution certificate is in my organizer window but is not in the list.

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to download a Distribution Profile from the Provisioning Portal as with any other profile. You have a choice between App Store (releasing) and Ad Hoc (testing) types.

Edit: http://developer.apple.com/ios/my/distribution/index.action has instructions at the bottom for how to do this.

Comment: I'll try it new again. Thanks for your help.